# Post by facebook comment box can't show image

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I'm using comment box on my website and it is working pretty well. It save comment and post them on the user wall (if checked) but it doesn't show any image/description also if the og tag are correct in the page (I've checked them with https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

How can I get images and description to show up on users wall?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the App ID that the comment plugin is set to.

Please follow the steps below:

1. Make App in Facebook Developers
2. Add site's URL to the App Setting
3. Get the code for comment plug in from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/
4. Paste the code's `<script>` part after body tag and `<div>` part on the area you wish.

Let me know if you still have problem